# How do I ask to leave because of weather?

Tags: management, manager, time-off

I'm not sure how to ask my boss if I can leave early because of weather (specifically snow). I came in this morning, to get some work done before it got worse. Well it's worse now and the roads are starting to get really bad. Not to mention, I live a half hour away in good weather; I'm already expecting a long trip home.

How should I ask my boss if I can leave early? He doesn't seem to be in a rush to leave himself, but I'm pretty sure he lives closer. Some co-workers haven't come in at all today. I can't seem to find a policy on my company's intranet regarding weather.

Comment: I just want to add - if this become a continuous problem and they don't *let* you leave when there is a serious reason to, look for another company/boss that has a better policy. No job is worth risking your life in *truly* bad weather. I work in a large department, my boss lets us WFH if we wish freely during weather. Another boss in my department does not let their team do the same. They normally look for jobs underneath my boss in a few winter seasons.

Comment: Would help to know a location.  Some areas look at snow differently.  3 feet of snow is "moderate commute time" in Manitoba, they call in the army in Toronto, and NYC starts rioting and looting like it's the end of the world.

Comment: Some locations have issues if there is 1cm of snow... some drivers should not be out with or without snow...

Comment: Key words to use are "safety" and "inclement" - e.g. "I'm worried about road safety conditions due to the inclement weather, so I will be leaving early working/remote."

Comment: @MattR "No job is worth risking your life in truly bad weather"...tell that to the members of the armed forces, emergency first responders, forest fire fighters, snow plow operators, public works road crews.  Being out in bad weather is part of their job description, and I bet a lot of them love what they do and believe its VERY worth putting their life on the line so others can live and be safe.

Comment: What is your location?  Local law might allow you to leave early if you use PTO/sick time, with little or no reason.

Comment: @ForwardEd While I agree with the sentiment of your comment, this is the Workplace stack exchange. Most of the posts here are "business-esque". I was not making a blanket statement to pick apart.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You say to your boss

> Hey boss. I'm a bit twitchy about getting home in the snow. Would it be alright if I left a bit early and made up the time (at home/later in the week/some other way that is acceptable in your organisation)?

Adjust tone to suit your relationship with your boss.

Comment: Any reasonable boss should accept this...

Comment: Any halfway decent boss should know to put the safety of his employees above all else. As long as it's clear your concern is legitimate, he should absolutely let you go!

Comment: May have to explain why leaving early is safer than leaving at the right time.

Comment: @TrevorD I have seen 30cm of snow arrive in under 2 hours : makes the trip home **a lot** more interesting...

Comment: @SolarMike Such a situation means it's safer to stay at work, rather than be caught in the storm.  Therefore justification of leaving early for safety is harder.

Comment: @TrevorD Some work places don't have the facilities... Some have kids that need feeding at home... the reasons are legion...

Comment: @TrevorD I'd rather drive through 2 inches of snow while it's still falling than through 6 inches of snow when it's clear. I can't think of a scenario where it would safer to stay, unless you are planning to spend the night.

Comment: @SolarMike That's a valid justification to use.

Comment: @SethR If necessary, yes.  Or take a bus, or wait for snow plows later in the day after rush hour.  There is lots of possibilities and it's important to know them.  We also all get ample warning before such storms, meaning it was unsafe to go to work in the first place.

Comment: @TrevorD In many places, those warnings are completely unreliable; I've had winter storm warnings caution six inches overnight and gotten a slight dusting, or very little warning for a huge storm. Additionally, snow tends to go with early sunsets, and driving in the snow at night is a double whammy, in addition to dealing with traffic-- which is often the bigger threat when the roads are bad.